# How to convert .dat file to geotiff (Raster file)

Tags: r, python-3.x

I have been working to covert the .dat file to giotiff file
here is a link for .dat file

**ftp://rainmap:Niskur+1404@hokusai.eorc.jaxa.jp/standard/v7/daily_G/00Z-23Z/202005/gsmap_gauge.20200501.0.1d.daily.00Z-23Z.v7.3112.0.dat.gz**

i have tried all the things Anything from R and Python is ok any body can help me please

Comment: `.dat` is a terribly imprecise file extension, it can be used with text or binary files with widely varying formats. This one in particular doesn't have an obvious (to me) identifier or signature. It would help to know what software/program generated this data.

Comment: Gio rain (spatial data) fall data  we don't kw how they generated but yeah it's a terrible format ,.......

Comment: Good luck, I'm unable to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAXA gsmap file has a specification on its [website](https://sharaku.eorc.jaxa.jp/GSMaP/document/new/DataFormatDescription_NRT7.pdf). The documentation shows that the data are float (double), little endian with 4 byte data (size argument in the `readBin` function). I wrote a `read_gsmap` function to get all of the data using the `readBin` function. Because the array is 3600 x 1200 we can read in all of the bits by using an n value of 3600*1200.

```
read_gsmap <- function(fname, nvals){
    ## gsmap daily world data is 4 byte little endian float
    on.exit(close(flcon))
    flcon <- file(fname, 'rb')
    readBin(flcon, "double", n = nvals, endian = "little", size = 4)
  }
```

Next we just create a matrix by row with the number of rows and columns documented on the climate website. This is because the data are ordered in row-wise in the binary.

```
nrow <- 1200
ncol <- 3600
filename <- "gsmap_gauge.20200501.0.1d.daily.00Z-23Z.v7.3112.0.dat"

data <- matrix(read_gsmap(filename, (nrow * ncol)),
           nrow = nrow,
           ncol = ncol,
           byrow = TRUE)
```

Then we can use the `raster` package to generate a raster from the matrix we just created. The documentation shows that the data are in degrees, so the crs should be EPSG 4326. We set the minimum x value to 0 and maximum to 360 because this is the start and end that is documented for this data. Because the raster now has an x-axis extent of 0 to 360, we need to use the `raster::rotate` function to convert this raster to -180 to 180 degrees (to get this into conventional gis coordinates). Finally we have the raster and can write it to a GeoTiff.

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(data,
        xmn = 0,
        xmx = 360,
        ymn = -60,
        ymx = 60,
        crs = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
        )

r <- rotate(r)
writeRaster(r, "gsmap_rainfall.tif")
```

[image]